# Text gradient <h1>

Tags: html, css, colors, gradient

I have a h1 tag text. Is it possible to give this text a shadow using CSS? (preferable without JavaScript).

Any help?

I need a color gradient from: #486882 to #2b4356

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-nonintrusive-css-text-gradients/

Comment: A shadow is possible in CSS (GIYF), but this is different to a gradient...

Comment: Thanks Seth, but it is only supported Chrome and Safari — or all webkit-based browsers

Answer (score 3):

Gradients and shadows are not the same:

Text-Shadow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-shadow

Text Gradient: http://matthewleak.co.uk/css3bob/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you have to master the cross browser compatibility.
Here is nice sample

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly specify a gradient in css for `text-shadow`. However, you can use two `text-shadow`s together to get the effect you want:

```
h1 { text-shadow: 0 0 0.2em #2b4356, 0 0 0.1em #486882 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup quite possible with CSS3.

text-shadow: XXpx XXpx 0px #2b4356;

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/pk7RT/5/)